# What's the scope for Gmail's OAuth2 IMAP access?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gmail, oauth-2.0

I'm using [google-api-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) and [imapclient](https://bitbucket.org/mjs0/imapclient) libraries to try get IMAP access to Gmail.

When going through the authentication flow, I'm getting "invalid scope" errors. I've tried both `https://mail.google.com` and `https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom` as scopes.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator

SCOPE = "https://mail.google.com"
# SCOPE = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"

oauth2decorator_gmail = OAuth2Decorator(client_id="CLIENT_ID",
                                   client_secret="CLIENT_SECRET",
                                   scope=SCOPE,
                                   callback_path='/mycallbackurl')

class AuthenticateSyncServices(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @oauth2decorator_gmail.oauth_required
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("Authenticated")
```

And here's the stacktrace:

```
INFO     2013-06-06 08:56:36,686 client.py:1304] Failed to retrieve access token: {
  "error" : "invalid_scope"
}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 68, in check_login
    handler_method(self, *args)
  File "/Users/John/Projects/my-app/backend/oauth2client/appengine.py", line 787, in get
    credentials = decorator.flow.step2_exchange(self.request.params)
  File "/Users/John/Projects/my-app/backend/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/John/Projects/my-app/backend/oauth2client/client.py", line 1310, in step2_exchange
    raise FlowExchangeError(error_msg)
FlowExchangeError: invalid_scope
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol:

The scope for IMAP and SMTP access is https://mail.google.com/